# JavaScript: How to parse and then render a collection of dictionary entries? (arrays, key-value, sorting problem)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting, key-value

I want to display a list of dictionary entries in a table using javascript, using some combination of arrays and key/value pairs.

Here is what I've got to work so far:

```js
let d = new Map();

d.set('stack', '[n] 1. an orderly pile 2. a list in which the next item to be removed is the most recently stored [v] 1. to arrange in order 2. to arrange in stacks')
d.set('overflow', '[n] 1. a large flow 2. the occurrence of surplus liquid')
;

document.write("<table>");

for (const [key, value] of d.entries()) {
document.write("<tr><td class=\"word\">"+key+": "+"</td>" + "<td class=\"def\">"+value+"</td>\n");
}

document.write("</table>");
```

```css
table {
    border: solid thin; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1.5px solid #aaa;
    padding: 4px 6px;
}
td.word {
    background-color: #cee5ec;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
td.def {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-left-width: 0px;
}
```

Which looks okay, but it would be better (easier to type a large number of entries, and language-agnostic) if I could prepare all entries as a string literal and have the script parse and reorganize it:

```js
let d = new Map();

let ddata = (`
stack: [n] 1. an orderly pile 2. a list in which the next item to be removed is the most recently stored [v] 1. to arrange in order 2. to arrange in stacks

overflow: [n] 1. a large flow 2. the occurrence of surplus liquid
`).split('\n');

for (let i = 0; i < ddata.length; i++) {
    ddata[i].split(': ');
    d.set(ddata[i][0]), d.set(ddata[i][1]);
}

document.write("<table>");

for (const [key, value] of d.entries()) {
document.write("<tr><td class=\"word\">"+key+": "+"</td>" + "<td class=\"def\">"+value+"</td>\n");
}

document.write("</table>");
```

```css
table {
    border: solid thin; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 4px 6px;
}
td.word {
    background-color: #cee5ec;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
td.def {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-left-width: 0px;
}
```

Performance in the browser is not really a concern at this point, as the end result will not be for a general audience. If performance does ever become a concern, I will serve the dictionary in sections.

The bigger issue right now is that the following code is not working as expected at all. Instead of splitting the string at the `:`, it's making arrays of individual letters:

```
ddata[i].split(': ');
    d.set(ddata[i][0]), d.set(ddata[i][1]);
```

Ideally, I would like to create breakpoints at the part-of-speech symbol (noun, verb, etc). I know this can be done with regex like `(\[\w*\])` to match `[n]` or `[noun]`. And then each numbered meaning after than could be separated using `\d.` to match `1.` `2.` and so on.

Here is a rough static HTML example of the desired end result:

```css
table {
    border: solid thin; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 4px 6px;
}
td.word {
    background-color: #cee5ec;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
td.def {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-left-width: 0px;
}

.pos {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.num {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 4px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="word">stack:</td><td class="def"><span class="pos">[n]</span> <span class="num">1.</span> an orderly pile <span class="num">2.</span> a list in which the next item to be removed is the most recently stored</br><span class="pos">[v]</span> <span class="num">1.</span> to arrange in order <span class="num">2.</span> to arrange in stacks</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="word">overflow:</td><td class="def"><span class="pos">[n]</span> <span class="num">1.</span> a large flow <span class="num">2.</span> the occurrence of surplus liquid</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

↑ Note the `</br>` in between `[n]` and `[v]` categories, the `<span>` tags wrapping `[n]` and `1.` (with classes `pos` and `num` respectively).

Putting it all together is turning into a long process of trial and error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.split` on a string creates a new array, it does not change anything "in place".

You have to store the results:

```js
const [ key, value ] = ddata[i].split(': ');
d.set(key, value);
```

You also might want to filter out empty lines:

```js
("...").split('\n').filter(s => s.length);
```

Also note that your new approach only works if your value strings do not contain `": "`. If you want to ensure only the *first* `": "` is used to split between key and value, you could do something like this:

```js
const [ key, ...values ] = ddata[i].split(": ");
d.set(key, values.join(": "));
```

```js
let d = new Map();

let ddata = (`
stack: [n] 1. an orderly pile 2. a list in which the next item to be removed is the most recently stored [v] 1. to arrange in order 2. to arrange in stacks

overflow: [n] 1. a large flow 2. the occurrence of surplus liquid
`).split('\n').filter(s => s.length);

for (let i = 0; i < ddata.length; i++) {
    const [ key, value ] = ddata[i].split(': ');
    d.set(key, value);
}

document.write("<table>");

for (const [key, value] of d.entries()) {
document.write("<tr><td class=\"word\">"+key+": "+"</td>" + "<td class=\"def\">"+value+"</td>\n");
}

document.write("</table>");
```

```css
table {
    border: solid thin; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 4px 6px;
}
td.word {
    background-color: #cee5ec;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
td.def {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-left-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful info! That solves the bulk of the problem. If you have any thoughts on the regex part please let me know. (I added a static HTML reference.) I've been struggling with it with limited success.

Comment: I think it makes sense to extract the parsing logic in to small steps (e.g. first separate the key from the definitions, and then get the type and descriptions of each definition). For example: you can start out simple with some messy code like I did here: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lx7do02/ Once everything works, you can improve the parsing using regular expressions. Maybe also write some unit tests to ensure the system is robust enough to deal with differently formatted strings!

Comment: Thank you for the jsfiddle example. That is also helpful. Unfortunately, when the second definition `overflow: [n] 1. a large flow 2. the occurrence of surplus liquid` is added to the string data, this second word doesn't get its own entry, but instead gets tacked onto the end of the definition of "stack". I'm trying to troubleshoot it.

Comment: I focused on parsing a single definition in the fiddle. You'll have to apply the logic for each line of your `ddata` string. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/atj5vprs/

Comment: Nice! Looks like I can customize the rest from here. I really appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

For yours, when you spit at "/n" it had lines that were empty so you would need to filter those out. This is what I came up with:

```
let d = new Map();

let ddata = `
stack: [n] 1. an orderly pile 2. a list in which the next item to be removed is the most recently stored [v] 1. to arrange in order 2. to arrange in stacks

overflow: [n] 1. a large flow 2. the occurrence of surplus liquid
`.split('\n') // Spits at newline
  .filter(ddata => ddata.length > 0) // Filters every line that is empty
  .map(ddata => ddata.split(':')) // Splits at colon
  .forEach(ddata => { // For each line adds the word/key and def/value to the map
    d.set(ddata[0], ddata[1].trim());
  })

document.write("<table>");

for (const [key, value] of d.entries()) {
  document.write("<tr><td class=\"word\">"+key+": "+"</td>" + "<td class=\"def\">"+value+"</td>\n");
}

document.write("</table>");
```